# My prefix is a german no

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a german no,
> My suffix is the age last years,
> My infix is the cage of a hunter,
> My whole is coming once again in a few weeks.

Comment: Math, I don't understand your second clue, it is very obscure in meaning, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> Nineteen?

My prefix is a german no,

> The german word for no is Nein, which is pronounced as an english **nine**

My suffix is the age last years,

> A bit of a stretch, but last year was 2019, so its 'age' would be 19(starting from the 2000), which would be its last **teen** year

My infix is the cage of a hunter,

> Ni **net** een, a net is a cage/trap of sorts that hunters use to catch fish and other animals

My whole is coming once again in a few weeks,

> The riddle was posted on the **nineteen** day of this month! Which will come around once again in 4ish weeks

Comment: Yes, your right. Great answer.